# Switch between Select All and Where clause dynamically in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, isnull

I want to write a T-SQL query for below conditions.

If the user provides a value for the parameter, run the query with the where clause.

```sql
SELECT * 
FROM TestDB 
WHERE CustomerId = @customer_id
```

If the user doesn't provide a value for the parameter, I want to return all the data

```sql
SELECT * 
FROM TestDB
```

Can I make it work in a single query, for example using `ISNULL()` or an alternative, without going for a stored procedure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add a condition to the `WHERE` clause which admits all records in the event the user parameter be null:

```
SELECT *
FROM TestDB
WHERE CustomerId = @customer_id OR @customer_id IS NULL;
```

Comment: I suggest one specify an `OPTION(RECOMPILE)` query hint with this technique in order to optimize the query for either use case.